# What will the XMLHttpRequest send Method hold?

Tags: ajax

What will the XMLHttpRequest send Method hold? What and all it can contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is your friend.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763706(VS.85).aspx

http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send-method

Short answer is: anything, but you might need to specify the content type in the headers.